# Caculating $\log(z^{p(z)})$ along a contour around the origin.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $R$ be a rectangle with vertices $1+i, -1+i, -1-i, 1-i$ and $f(z) = \log(z^{p(z)})$ where $p(z)$ is a polynomial. What is the argument change of $f(z)$ around the contour?